# Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden (403)

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am using `AFNetworking` 3.1.0 to make a http request.
It shows below after i made the request. The code i made the request is in the bottom. The url below you can see is not visitable without ssl VPN.

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011
>   "Request failed: forbidden (403)"
>   UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL:
>   https://223.71.215.70/web/1/http/0/10.100.5.105:6666/entry } { status
>   code: 403, headers {
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 238;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
>       Date = "Wed, 14 Dec 2016 14:27:48 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";
>       "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://223.71.215.70/web/1/http/0/10.100.5.105:6666/entry,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403),
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<3c21444f 43545950
>   45204854 4d4c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f4945 54462f2f 44544420
>   48544d4c 20322e30 2f2f454e 223e0a3c 68746d6c 3e3c6865 61643e0a
>   3c746974 6c653e34 30332046 6f726269 6464656e 3c2f7469 746c653e
>   0a3c2f68 6561643e 3c626f64 793e0a3c 68313e46 6f726269 6464656e
>   3c2f6831 3e0a3c70 3e596f75 20646f6e 27742068 61766520 7065726d
>   69737369 6f6e2074 6f206163 63657373 202f7765 622f312f 68747470
>   2f302f31 302e3130 302e352e 3130353a 36363636 2f656e74 72790a6f
>   6e207468 69732073 65727665 722e3c2f 703e0a3c 2f626f64 793e3c2f
>   68746d6c 3e0a>} Request failed: forbidden (403)

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: config)
manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer() // AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: .prettyPrinted)
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer() // AFJSONResponseSerializer(readingOptions: .mutableContainers)
//      manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = ["text/html"]
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = ["application/json", "text/json", "text/JavaScript", "text/html", "text/plain"]
let policy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: .none)
policy.allowInvalidCertificates = true
policy.validatesDomainName = false
manager.securityPolicy = policy

manager.post(url, parameters: para, progress: nil, success: { (task:URLSessionDataTask, a:Any?) in
            print(123)
        }) { (task: URLSessionDataTask?, error: Error) in
//          print(task?.description)
            print(error)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Comment: From what I can tell the response is image/png (at lease that's what I'm getting) which is not in your manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes. Do you use any type of authentication?

Comment: @EugenDimboiu That is not a image, "Content-Type" = "text/html;

Comment: That's what it shows to me when I click the URL (image), but it's probably because I'm not using a VPN. Are you sure it's not a authentication issue? Try to open the link from a incognito browser - can you see the content you're looking for without needing to authenticate ?

Comment: @EugenDimboiu sry, what is a incognito browser. I can not open it thorough  Safari. Let me google it.

Comment: new private window if you're using safari

Comment: @EugenDimboiu really? safari tells me it can not open it, because it cannot establish a secure connection with the license server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130617/discussion-between-eugen-dimboiu-and-).

Answer (score 0):

I found that if my phone clock was out of sync...Maybe check that your phone is set to the right time "auto zone" and see if that works...

Reference URL: https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Charge-HR/Can-t-set-up-error-Forbidden-403/td-p/1053680